# MySQL Select statement based on multiple joins

Tags: mysql, join

I have a `select statement` that requires me to `join` multiple tables (4 tables).

My tables are the following:

1. Teams

[image]

2. Team_User

[image]

3. Tournament_User

[image]

4. Tournaments

[image]

I need to get the `teams` from a `certain tournament`. My logic is at it follows:

In `Tournament_User` table i can find the `users` that are in a `tournament`. In `Team_User` i can find the `users` that are in a `team`.

To get the teams from a certain tournament I tried the following `query`:

```
SELECT t.id FROM Teams t
JOIN Team_User tu on tu.team_id = t.id
JOIN Tournament_User tru on tru.user_id = tu.user_id
JOIN Tournaments tr on tr.id = tru.tournament_id
WHERE tr.id = "tournamentId";
```

It gets me the `correct teams`, but it `duplicates` them.

I also added `DISTINCT` which it gets me the correct teams and without duplicating them, but I wonder if I can retrieve the records as expected using only `joins` and without `DISTINCT`.

Also, my records can't contain duplicates and there are no duplicates, I somehow managed to bring them duplicated based on my query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result)

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume there is a Users table in your schema. There is a many-to-many relation between Teams and Users as well as a many-to-many relation between Users and Tournaments. That means each tournament will be related to many users, which in turn means that even if all users are from the same team, your query result will have each team as many times as there are users from it in the given tournament. The nature of the relations between these tables necessitates that you use DISTINCT.